# PowerShell search system path for shortcut

Tags: powershell, vim, path, get-childitem

On Windows, when I enter `gvim` it finds the file under `C:\Program Files (x86)` even though that vim directory is not in my system path.  So how does it find it?

On Linux, I can enter this command, which shows that there is a link `/usr/bin/gvim`.

```
locate gvim
```

However, that does not work in PowerShell.  I also tried this but it does not work because apparently `-path` expects a single directory.

```
gci "gvim*" -path "$env:PATH" -r | select FullName
```

How do I find the shortcut that is used?  Answers using PowerShell are preferred, but any elegant solution is okay.

Comment: Have you tried ***get-command gvim.exe***?

Comment: Perfect; thanks!  `get-command gvim` shows `C:\Windows\gvim.bat`.

Comment: ... or use plain old `where gvim`

Comment: That works in cmd.exe but not PowerShell.  Still, it gets the correct results as well.

Comment: Your approach: `gci "gvim*" -path ("$env:PATH" -split ';') | select FullName` as `gci` accepts `<String[]>` (i.e. an array) as `-path` argument.

Comment: Cool, that is helpful too.